# Can someone give me tips on how to use the substring function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query where the first column display name length the second is title or courtesy I have done those but I'm having trouble with my third column. It is supposed  to use substring and display first name initial and last name initial can anyone tell me how to add this function to what I already have?

Here is the query

```
SELECT 'Your full name is ' + CAST(LEN(FirstName) + LEN(LastName) AS VARCHAR(12)) + ' character(s).' AS [Length of Employee Name], 
       CASE TitleOfCourtesy WHEN 'Mr.' THEN 'Mister '
                            WHEN 'mrs. ' THEN 'Miss'
                            WHEN 'Ms.' THEN 'Miss '
                            WHEN 'Dr.' THEN 'Doctor '
                            ELSE '' END + TitleOfCourtesy + LastName AS title
FROM dbo.Employees
```

Comment: substring(FirstName from 1 for 1), or perhaps substring(FirstName,1,1)?

Comment: added `sql-server` tag based on the `+` for string concatenation and the `[..]` "quoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(since you used LEN I assume you are using SQL Server)

You mean something like this?

```
substring(FirstName,1,1) + substring(LastName,1,1)
```

In general it is like this :

```
substring(expression, startPosition, lenght)
```

Comment: As defined by ANSI/ISO SQL: <character substring function> ::=
SUBSTRING <left paren> <character value expression> FROM <start position>
[ FOR <string length> ] [ USING <char length units> ] <right paren>

Comment: Intresting and definitely more clear, but I tried it in SQL Server and didn't work.

Comment: Thanks all but how do i incorporate it with the rest of the query like do i concantenate it or how do i add that part to the rest?

Comment: @mistylove98 if you want it as another column , just separate it with a comma (after "as tite") and write the substring. If you give and example of desired output that would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you @amir M That is what I was looking for. Thanks everyone for taking time to help me

Comment: No problem, @Stephan's answer is another soloution. you should mark one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I would use LEFT() instead of substring.

```
DECLARE @Employees TABLE (FirstName VARCHAR(25),LastName VARCHAR(25), TitleOfCourtesy VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @Employees
VALUES  ('Bob','Brown','Mr.'),
        ('Olivia','Taylor','M rs.'),
        ('Grace','Stevens','Ms.'),
        ('Theodor','Seuss','Dr.');


SELECT  'Your full name is ' + CAST(LEN(FirstName) + LEN(LastName) AS VARCHAR(12)) + ' character(s).' AS [Length of Employee Name], 
        CASE Replace(TitleOfCourtesy, ' ','') --Gets rid of any white space
                WHEN 'Mr.'      THEN 'Mister'
                WHEN 'mrs.'     THEN 'Miss'
                WHEN 'Ms.'      THEN 'Miss'
                WHEN 'Dr.'      THEN 'Doctor'
                ELSE ''
        END + ' ' + LastName AS title,
        CONCAT(LEFT(FirstName,1),'.',LEFT(LastName,1),'.') AS Initials
FROM @Employees
```

Results:

```
Length of Employee Name                      title                            Initials
-------------------------------------------- -------------------------------- --------
Your full name is 8 character(s).            Mister Brown                     B.B.
Your full name is 12 character(s).           Miss Taylor                      O.T.
Your full name is 12 character(s).           Miss Stevens                     G.S.
Your full name is 12 character(s).           Doctor Seuss                     T.S.
```